# Command block runs even if other one does nothing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have two command blocks running in an infinite loop. One is changing gamemodes of anyone who isn't in Adventure mode (other than specific people with my special admin tag), and the other one tells them them a message using `/tellraw`. The `tellraw` command block displays it's text even if the `gamemode` one doesn't do anything. Anyone have a solution for this? As long as it still includes the infinite loop and the two command blocks.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes, I have. I always do.

Comment: Great! *So show us what you've tried*. It will help us give you a better answer, and the community responds better when we see your own effort in trying to solve your problem.

Comment: We don't allow signatures in questions, either. Please, try to learn how we work. We are significantly different from most other sites.

Comment: ok, fine then...

Comment: @DragonSlayr15001 It sounds like you might be new to using command blocks.  I recommend you read the [wiki page on command blocks](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Command_Block).  It will help you understand the features of command blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "conditional" setting of a command block provides ths behavior you are looking for. If you set a command-block to conditional within it's gui, it will only run if the command block behind it successfully ran it's last command. However, in your case, this may not be the best option. If you use the conditional setting in your adventure-mode machine, whenever any player gets put into adventure mode, every player would get the tellraw message, not just the one that got changed. Instead, I'd suggest switching the order of your commands, and adjusting them slightly. First, print your message to all players not in adventure mode (who aren't admin-tagged), then set the gamemode of all non-adventure mode (non admin) players to adventure. This will only print the message to those who will be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, this is one of the first times someone has actually explained the answer in one go! Though, I am a new user, so...